# Get current working directory name instead of path in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a CLI application that needs to use the name of the current directory.

I can get the path to the current directory with `process.cwd()`. How can I get the current directory name instead of the whole path?

Is it OK to do something like the following?

```
process.cwd().split('/').slice(-1)[0]
```

It works, but it feels brittle. What is the best and most robust way of doing this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Even though the code in the answer works, you should use [`path.basename()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) to get the name of the last portion of a path because:

- It works across operating systems (windows and unix-like systems use different path separators)
- It ignores trailing directory separators (i.e. the last `/` in `/path/to/cwd/`)

Additionally, and for extra safety, you should use [`path.resolve()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths) because it normalizes the path before getting the base name, getting rid of path-related quirks.

If you can get the `/path/to/cwd` with `process.cwd()`, then the following will give you the name of the directory (`"cwd"` in the example):

```
path.basename(process.cwd())
```

Add `path.resolve()` for extra safety:

```
path.basename(path.resolve(process.cwd()))
```

or even:

```
path.basename(path.resolve())
```

### Example:

```
const path = require('path');

function slice(pathName) {
  const res = pathName.split(path.sep).slice(-1)[0];
  console.log('slicer  ', pathName, '=>', `'${res}'`);
}

function basename(pathName) {
  const res = path.basename(path.resolve(pathName));
  console.log('basename', pathName, '=>', `'${res}'`);
}

slice('/path/to/cwd'); // cwd
basename('/path/to/cwd'); // cwd

slice('/path/to/cwd/'); // ''
basename('/path/to/cwd/'); // cwd

// Other valid paths
slice('/path/to/cwd/..'); // '..'
basename('path/to/cwd/..'); // cwd

slice('.'); // '.'
basename('.'); // <current directory name>
```

#### process.cwd()

```
Returns: <string>
```

> The process.cwd() method returns the current working directory of the Node.js process.
>
> ```
> console.log(`Current directory: ${process.cwd()}`);
> ```

This is **guaranteed** to be the absolute path to the current working directory. Use this!

#### path.basename(path[, ext])

```
path <string>
ext <string> An optional file extension
Returns: <string>
```

> The `path.basename()` method returns the last portion of a path, similar to the Unix basename command. Trailing directory separators are ignored, see path.sep.
>
> ```
> path.basename('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html');
> // Returns: 'quux.html'
>
> path.basename('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux.html', '.html');
> // Returns: 'quux'
> ```
>
> A TypeError is thrown if path is not a string or if ext is given and is not a string.

#### path.resolve([...paths])

> ```
> ...paths <string> A sequence of paths or path segments
> Returns: <string>
> ```
>
> The path.resolve() method resolves a sequence of paths or path segments into an absolute path.
>
> The given sequence of paths is processed from right to left, with each subsequent path prepended until an absolute path is constructed. For instance, given the sequence of path segments: /foo, /bar, baz, calling path.resolve('/foo', '/bar', 'baz') would return /bar/baz.
>
> If after processing all given path segments an absolute path has not yet been generated, the current working directory is used.
>
> The resulting path is normalized and trailing slashes are removed unless the path is resolved to the root directory.
>
> Zero-length path segments are ignored.
>
> **If no path segments are passed, path.resolve() will return the absolute path of the current working directory.**

If you can use `process.cwd()` you don't need `path.resolve()` in other cases, use it!.

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [path.basename](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext):

```
const path = require('path'); 
path.basename(CWD)
```

> The [path.basename()](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) method returns the last portion of a path.
>   Trailing directory separators are ignored.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since I don't have a path to a file but to the current working directory, path.dirname would give me the parent directory, i.e. `path.basename(path.dirname('path/to/cwd')) === 'to'` but I'm looking for `cwd`

Comment: @lucascaro Edited, the above should work as intended